# How to create a Google oauth2 token from a Firebase user?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

I am trying to get a valid Google oauth2 token for a user that has logged in through Firebase. I need a Google token so I can authenticate this user through other Google services (not just Firebase).

I am currently using the firebase-admin for this on a server and passing that user's Firebase token to nodejs. I'm doing something like this:

```
  
    admin.auth().verifyIdToken(tokenId)
      .then((decoded) => {
        const uid = decoded.uid;

        console.log(tokenId);
        admin.auth().createCustomToken(uid).then((t) => {
          console.log(t);
        })
    }
```

However neither the token I'm passing to the admin or the custom token seems to work for other Google services. I'm able to create a custom token, just not sure if or how I can use that to get a google oauth token for that user.